# How to write and read file paths to a binary file using Julia

Tags: parsing, julia, character, binaryfiles

I am trying to establish my own file format and I am using binary as a base for it. I have to write many things of many different data types to this file but I seem to be having trouble with reading file paths back from the binary file, specifically, the "\" character seems to be causing me some issues.  I know it is an escape character but it is behaving in a way I would not expect.

The following is what was written into the file...

```
"C:This\\is\\also\\a\\test;"
```

and I use this to read it back out (Note: I am using ';' as a delimiter as I can write an arbitrary number of paths each of arbitrary length to this file)

```
 reading = true
 while reading
      readbytes!(s,chartemp,1)
       
      recentlyread = Char(chartemp[1])
      @printf("char: %s\n",recentlyread)
      if recentlyread == ';'
           reading = false
           break
      end
      mat_folder = string(mat_folder,recentlyread)
 end
```

and what gets read back out is this...

```
"String[][\"C:This\\\\is\\\\also\\\\a\\\\test\"]"
```

I'm not sure if I am doing this the best way or where all these extra "\" are coming from. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to come up with your file format? For most purposes, it's better to use an established file format. Also, an MWE consisting of file + complete code to read the file would be helpful.

Comment: If you have two \ characters inside your file, then that's where the damage happens. Your problems stems from writing the binary file.